# AJAX / PHP Search Not working

Tags: php, ajax

I am attempting to create a searchbox using php and AJAX. However, when I type a name already in the database into searchbox, no suggestion appear. Nothing happens.

I have tested the php and seems to be working. What am I missing?

Code update with PDO

```
require_once('connect_pdo.php');

$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

$stmtus = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Schools` WHERE `School` LIKE :School");
$stmtus->bindValue(':School', '%' . $searchTerm . '%');
$searchTerm = $_POST['school'];;
$stmtus -> execute();


while ($result = $stmtus->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$school = $result['School'];

}
echo json_encode($school);
```

AJAX

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#school").autocomplete({
                    source:'schoolfind.php',
                    minLength:3
                });
            });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<label>What school does the child attend<input  type="text" name="school" id="school" /></label>
```

Comment: That is not how prepared statements work. You need to put a placeholder in the query. The driver then binds the term with the placeholder. I assume the JS works with this comment, you should narrow down the scope of the question to being PHP or JS. `SELECT * FROM Schools WHERE School LIKE :School` and add the `%` on the binding.

Comment: You have a label, but no input?

Comment: The updated code would throw a parse error, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'`. What is your actual code?

Comment: @JayBlanchard. I fixed the prepared statement. The input is inside the label

Comment: Now that you've fixed your prepared statement and your PHP works properly there is nothing here which would lead to a problem that we can see. You're absolutely sure there are no errors in the console and you can clearly watch the AJAX request/response in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: @JayBlanchard. I restarted my browser.. I Found SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined

Comment: That's the only two. JQuery is referring to a LIbrary

Comment: So - jquery isn't loaded properly. If it isn't, your autocomplete will not work.

Comment: How do I fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: Change the `http://` to `https://` on all of your jQuery sources to cure the one error. Do that, reload and see what errors are left.

Comment: Thanks for all your advise. Errors are now clear, but still not working

Comment: All errors are clear? Did you watch the request in the network tab of the developer tools?

Comment: To be totally honest, I am still a new developer, I haven't done that yet. I have done so now, but nothing happens.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: IE. I have just realised that there is requests running. URL Protocol Method Result Type Received Taken Initiator Wait‎‎ Start‎‎ Request‎‎ Response‎‎ Cache read‎‎ Gap‎‎
/clientarea/schoolfind.php?term=Basti HTTPS GET 200 text/html 197 B 31 ms XMLHttpRequest 119434 0 31 0 0 0

Comment: There should be a response to that request.

Comment: There is, But I have no idea what it means. Method = Get, Protocol HTTPS, Result 200, Type = Text/html, Initiator = XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Try it in Chrome, you'll get better information. I have to duck out for now but I'll check later.

Comment: Thanks. I did. It gave three errors which have shown block. It all reffered to googleapis and 1 to codejquery. I have removed them. Still no luck.

Comment: @JayBlanchard. I have removed all libraries, only added libraries suggested on https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. Still no luck

Comment: @JayBlanchard. In Chrome I can see in Network tab that the correct form is called. But nothing displays

Comment: What does the response tab show?

Comment: Sadly, I have no idea. I don't see a response tab

Comment: @chris85. Found it. No data available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any bind anchor you use (like `:School`) needs to appear **unquoted** in your query string. I.e., don't do this:

```
$stmtus = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Schools` WHERE `School` LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'");
$stmtus->bindParam(':School', $searchTerm);
```

Do this:

```
$stmtus = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Schools` WHERE `School` LIKE :School");
$stmtus->bindValue(':School', '%' . $searchTerm . '%');
```